# Copy specific cells of a table to another page

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am intending to copy specific cells of a table to another page, I did tried out on copying. However, I could only copy the whole table and not specific cells. I have the example code below.

For example, I have

```
Product ID | Product Name | Qty | Price
-----------------------------------------------------
     1     |   Adidas     | 1   |  $50  |  Delete Btn
```

I want this content to be copied onto my `checkoutList`, but excluding the `Delete btn`, which is the last cell. May I know how to do it?

```
<table id="myList">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product Name</td>
                        <td>Qty</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This the table that will be populated with the copied content

```
<table id="checkoutList">
            </table>
```

This is my copy table function.

```
function copyTable() {


      window.location.href = "#/app/checkOut";


      //copyTable
      var source = document.getElementById('myList');
      var destination = document.getElementById('checkoutList');
      var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
      copy.setAttribute('id', 'checkoutList');
      destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);

    }
```

Comment: Tables are there to display information not to store them. Instead of copying data from the table in fact you should keep the user's purchased list in an array/object structure and pass a filtered or non filtered version of this data to the checkout stage to generate a new table accordingly there.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for .children property.